# Should I Write Lengthy SQL Query or Breakdown into Few Iterations

Tags: mysql, performance, iteration

I have a very lengthy SQL query to fetch the expected output but on the other side, I also can generate the expected output by using multiple iterations.

Which one should I use?
I care about performance and writing better code.

- By using length SQL query it takes around 3000ms to generate the output
- Need about 4 ~ 5 iterations to generate the output

#### What is the query/code is doing

This code is generating the total number of the forecast record based on the financial year regardless the total number is 0 or not.

#### Using Length SQL Query

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('FY\'', SUBSTR(`quarters`.fy, 3), ' Q', `quarters`.fy_quarter) AS name,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM
            member_project_stages 
        WHERE
            YEAR ( member_project_stages.start_at ) = `quarters`.fy 
            AND QUARTER ( member_project_stages.start_at ) = `quarters`.fy_quarter 
            AND member_project_stages.stage_id = 9 
    ) AS actual,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        projects AS a 
    WHERE
        ( a.forecast IS NOT NULL AND a.forecast > '' ) 
        AND a.forecast LIKE CONCAT( '%FY\'', SUBSTR( `quarters`.fy, 3 ), '%' ) 
        AND a.forecast LIKE CONCAT( '% Q', `quarters`.fy_quarter, '%' ) 
        AND a.deleted_at IS NULL 
    GROUP BY
        a.forecast 
    ) AS forecast 
FROM
    `member_project_stages`,
    (
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 9 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 9 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 6 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 6 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        CURDATE()) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        CURDATE()) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter UNION
    SELECT YEAR
        (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH )) AS fy,
        QUARTER (
        DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH )) AS fy_quarter
    ) AS `quarters`
GROUP BY
    `quarters`.fy,
    `quarters`.fy_quarter"
```

#### Using Iteration

```
for(...) {
    run SQL query
}

for(...) {
    using the previous output and run SQL query again
}

for(...) {
    using the previous output and run SQL query again
}

for(...) {
    using the previous output and run SQL query again
}

Finally I have my output
```

Comment: Test both variants. Choose a more suitable option. We can't decide which option is preferable INSTEAD OF YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that interacting with DB is costlier. Hence people prefer combining several queries into 1 query to optimize the performance. 
And for better code, why not explain the logic in comments.

Comment: I see. You are talking about the cost of calling the query from database? That makes more sense.